# jQuery if else and selected value from select tag

Tags: jquery

Why can't I get the value selected from my  input, am I doing something wrong?

```
 if($('#target option:selected').text() == "add")
                    $("#add").show(selectedEffect, options, 500, callback );
                 else if ($('#target option:selected').text() == "exit")
                    $("#exit").show(selectedEffect, options, 500, callback );
                 else if ($('#target option:selected').text() == "refuse")
                    $("#refuse").show(selectedEffect, options, 500, callback );
                 else
                    alert('test');
```

Comment: Would probably need to see your HTML to go with that.  By the way, `.text()` on an `<option>` will get the label, `.val()` on the `<select>` will get the currently selected option value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var target = $('#target option:selected').val();

if(target == "add")
    $("#add").show(selectedEffect, options, 500, callback );
else if ($('#target option:selected').text() == "exit")
    $("#exit").show(selectedEffect, options, 500, callback );
else if ($('#target option:selected').text() == "refuse")
    $("#refuse").show(selectedEffect, options, 500, callback );
else
alert('test');
```

Check it out here http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 2):

If you want the value use [`.val()` method.](http://api.jquery.com/val/)  The [`.text()` method](http://api.jquery.com/text/) returns the inner text of the element selected. The `.val()` method will return the value attribute of the element selected.  It is also of note that when using val() method on a select element.  You do not have to get the selected option in the selector, you can simply call val() on the select element itself to get the selected value.

```
$('#target').val();
```

If the value attribute of the selected option is what you want. Then from your example this will work.

```
switch ($('#target').val()) {
  case "add":
    $("#add").show(selectedEffect, options, 500, callback );
    break;
  case "exit":
    $("#exit").show(selectedEffect, options, 500, callback );
    break;
  case "refuse":
    $("#refuse").show(selectedEffect, options, 500, callback );
    break;
  default
    alert('test');
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#colorselector').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == 'red')
      {
        $("#divid").show();
      }
      else
      {
        $("#divid").hide();
      }
    });
});
</script>
```

Do like this for every value, Change the values as per your data.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the text content, and not the value property, then it is possible that you need [to trim whitespace](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/).

Though in your case, you don't really need the `==` comparison. Your code can be greatly reduced if you just use the text you get back to build the selector.

```
   // get (and trim) the text content
var txt = $.trim( $('#target option:selected').text() );

$('#' + txt).show(selectedEffect, options, 500, callback );
```